# How can I rephrase this sentence without "itself"?

Tags: word-choice, subcontinental-english, reflexives

I would like to know an alternative to using "itself" in this sentence, not forgoing the emphasis on today - which was added by including it.

> "There is nothing that I have, which needs to be discussed today itself"

It is normal to use a sentence such as the above in India, but native English speakers might not agree.

Comment: Perhaps "right away" in place of "today itself."  Also "this very day," though maybe not as common... (US)

Comment: @KaushikNayak ... just to be clear - does "itself" apply to "nothing", or to "today"? Does your sentence mean that the you have nothing to discuss today, (but you maybe have something for later)? Or that none of the things that you have (if any) needs to be discussed today? Or something else? [The difference is very subtle, but I would have a different phrasing for each option]

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/421002/177853

Comment: @ArchContrarian : The context  could be something like this -  "I have things to discuss, which I could discuss  today or tomorrow, but it is not important or mandated that I discuss it today 'itself', unlike other days in the past, where it was important to have it discussed on the same day."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most English dialects, "today itself" would not be used in this way. Instead, if we want to be clear that we are making no assertion about the situation on other days, we'd say:

> "... **today specifically**." or, "... **[specifically](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20specifically&oq=define%20specifically&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9092j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) today**."

There are some alternatives to ***specifically*** that could also do, both single words and phrases. Examples: '... that must *necessarily* be discussed today'; '... that can *only* be discussed today'.

However, most people would leave out 'specifically' altogether, and also simplify the sentence a bit.

> ***I have nothing that needs to be discussed today***

... and as someone commented above, you could also emphasise by replacing "today" with "this very day" (although that's a bit old fashioned).